# About the MinIO's backup

Tags: minio, object-storage

I used the mc mirror command to perform master-slave replication, and found that it only synchronized the data of the Buckets, but not others, such as policies, groups, users, etc. If I want to synchronize these as well, what should I do? Or how should MinIO be properly backed up?

Answer (score 0):

Site replication can help you achieve this. Please find the replated doc: https://min.io/docs/minio/kubernetes/upstream/operations/install-deploy-manage/multi-site-replication.html